# For a loss of reputation

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm a light snack for a panda;
>   For my purpose, "Get a duck!"
>   I hear knights do well without me;
>   AA members?  They'd be stuck!

**What Am I?**

> I didn't say, "Perhaps knights do well without me."  I didn't say "Maybe knights do well without me."  Both of those would have fit my sense of meter just fine. I chose "I hear" for a reason.

Comment: Why "for a loss of reputation"?

Comment: @R.Dye Sorry for your loss then.

Comment: @JavaSciptCoder For a "comedown." A "loss of reputation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I am going to build on @WeShall's answer who build on @ZachThePilot's answer.

It is...

> **(parachute) Canopy** (actually, "Parachutes.")

I'm a light snack for a panda

> Panda eat's mostly leaves, stems and **shoot**s of various bamboo species, two of them would be a pair-of-shoots, a light snack.  A light snack is also a Canape

For my purpose, "Get a duck!"

> "get a duck to do it" means get someone else to do something; you can get someone else to make your canape's and also you can offer fois gras (goose or duck liver) as a canape

I hear knights do well without me

> Pavilions (canopies) are the best I can do here.

AA members? They'd be stuck !!

> All Americans were the 82nd Airborne Division. While they'd be in a jam w/o guns I'd say this is more likely a play on words, they'd be stuck without their parachutes, especially if their canopy doesn't open.

** UPDATE **

Ok, tried again but I'm not at all sure how some fit.

Comment: You still haven't quite got it, but you've come closer than anyone else. Still, there were never any type of firearms intended in any of this . . . And I still haven't heard anything decent . . . 8-P @Paul – R. Dye 24 mins ago   
add a comment

Comment: Sorry @R.Dye that's the best I can come up with.

Comment: OK.  You finally said "parachutes." No one else used the entire word.  I would have taken "parachute" (singular), even though that does not **quite** fit the first line.  "I hear" refers to a homophones clue.  What sounds like "knights," and what do they do just fine without parachutes?  And the main purpose of a parachute?  Well, if you want to do **that,** you **could** just get a duck. A goose would work, too. @Paul

Comment: Complete explanation: "PARACHUTES."  "For a loss or reputation"="A comedown.  "A light snack for a panda"="Pair o' Shoots."  "For my purpose, get a duck!" ("Getting down..").  "I hear Knights" = "Nights" "do well without me"=Night falls just fine without a parachute.  "AA members, they'd be stuck."=Members of the 82nd Airbourne, the paratroopers, who would be stuck without parachutes. (I was told, by a retire 82nd member, that AA was "Anti-Aircraft." He lied. It's "All American.") ALSO, while paratroopers cannot jump without parachutes, Knights (in chess) *can* jump.

Comment: @R.Dye is *also* Anti-Aircraft.  There's a lot of acronym overload in the military.

Answer (score 1):

**My best guess:**

> A shoot!

- A light snack for a Panda

> Bamboo is classified as a shoot

- For my purpose: Get a duck!

> If you are being shot at, ducking is an obvious reaction

- I hear knights do well without me

> I am reminded of the book "A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's court" when an engineer is transported back to the days of knights and nobles, and wins a jousting tournament with his trusty six-shoot

- AA members, they'd be stuck

> This one gave me the most trouble. The best AA I could come up with was "all American" a common sports term. This makes sense because Americans are often very attached to their guns

Not 100% certain, but I think I'm close

Comment: You got the part about the panda-snack partly right.  You're very close.  The rest, not so much. For example, what your saying is, "For the purpose of "a shoot," get a duck!  But this does not quite make sense.  If you're going to look at the third line, use the entire line! The all-American part is a miss, but looking at those letters carefully might get you around to what you need. The title is also a hint, if you rephrase part with another word that means the same thing.  If you can get that, I expect everything to fall into place.  ;-).

Comment: Maybe the panda snack refers to 'Eats(,) Shoots and Leaves'?

Comment: Huh.  How about that? ;-) @boboquack. (Oh, and that "your" in my comment above is a typo.  Yeh.  A typo.)

Comment: @ZachThePilot Forgot to @ you.  Check comment above.  And the "your" is a typo. **Nothing** more.  Clear?  ;-)

Comment: @ZachThePilot Ack!  You were more right than I knew!  Check "you're" answer again, as you have something **else** right.  If I tell you, it will give too much away, and take some of the fun.  Suffice it to say (for now), someone told me (incorrectly) that it meant something **else!**. &$@%#!!!

Comment: Oh, dear God, do I feel stupid!  Does @ZachthePilot have **anything** to do with **Howard?**

Comment: Ah, I believe AA members is referring to AAA road side assistance. Not sure how it applies yet though

Comment: @PaigeMeinke. No.  Heck with it; it was **my** mistake.  "All American" was correct.  I was told it stood for something else, by someone who **should** have known, which is **why** I asked him.  Now I think what he told me was some sort of inside joke, which I will explain later.  (I can't, yet.  It would give too much away.)

Comment: @ZachThePilot See my note to Paige, above.  My apologies! It **was** an honest mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it could be a (though a partial answer)

> bamboo

As,

I'm a light snack for a panda;

> A panda feeds generally on bamboo shoots / trees

For my purpose, "Get a duck!"

> To  be explored ...

I hear knights do well without me;

> Here, knights refer to knights in Chess, who can *jump* for which they do not require bamboo poles (usually used in pole vaults / such high jumps)

AA members? They'd be stuck!

> Not sure, but AA is for *Alcoholics Anonymous* and fermentation of few types of spirits/breweries involve bamboo sticks (refer: https://books.google.co.in/books?isbn=9712305058) and AA members cannot proceed without these bamboo sticks, perhaps!

Comment: LOLOLOL!  You are pretty far off on most of this, but you *did* come up with another use of "knights" than I intended, the chess one.  So you are correct that "Knights [in chess can jump] 'do well' without me."  But you failed to account for the rest of line 3, which was chosen with purpose.  @Mea Culpa Nay. Do I need to provide another hint?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to build on @ZachThePilot's answer.

It is...

> **Shoot**

I'm a light snack for a panda

> Panda eat's mostly leaves, stems and **shoot**s of various bamboo species

For my purpose, "Get a duck!"

> Find a duck, let's go **shoot**ing

I hear knights do well without me

> Knights use swords. They don't **shoot** opponents. They would be just fine.

AA members? They'd be stuck !!

> Alcoholics Anonymous !? They would be stuck if there was a photo**shoot**

For a loss of reputation...

> Oh **Shoot** !! I totally forgot to include this.

Comment: No.  Sorry.  I already said what the AA was in a comment above, and it isn't Alcoholics Anonymous.